# Accessing scope variable of a function from another function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

I'm new to angularjs and i have trouble accessing a scope variable of a function from another function.

**1st function**

```
$scope.getCustomer = function (customer_id) {


                        ABCServices.wts.customer.customerList({customerId:customer_id}).then(function (data) {

                            console.log("^^^^^ABC show^^^^^");
                            $scope.wtsdata = data;

                            console.log($scope.wtsdata);

                        });

                    };
```

So here i want to access `$scope.wtsdata` in my second function. When i try to access it it gives me a undefined error.How to do this?

**2nd function**

```
$scope.selectCustomer = function (item) {

                    $scope.item = item;


                    if (item.length === 8) {

                        $scope.getCustomer(item);


                        console.log("Check"+$scope.wtsdata);

                    }

                };
```

Comment: Are both functions in same controller or different?

Comment: @Rakeschand same controller

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways

(i)use **[$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope)** in this case

(ii) Declare the $scope variable outside if **both functions** belong to **the same controller** otherwise you can make use of **[Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)** to share the variable among controllers,

```
 ABCServices.wts.customer.customerList({customerId:customer_id}).then(function (data) {
          console.log("^^^^^ABC show^^^^^");
          $rootScope.wtsdata = data;           
});

$scope.selectCustomer = function (item) {
     $scope.item = item;
     if (item.length === 8) {
     $scope.getCustomer(item);
     console.log("Check"+$rootScope.wtsdata);
   }
 };
```

Comment: Using $rootscope to share scope data is generally considered bad practice.

Comment: @DanielBornstrand I have explained all the scenarios, using $rootscope in this context is not a bad practice

Comment: still i get undefined error

Comment: @AlphaDog make sure you have injected $rootScope to your controller

Comment: Yes it is, using a factory or service to share the data is much better practice in this scenario. That way the you get the traceability from dependency injection. Any developer that has used an application where $rootscope were widely used to share data can attest to this.

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes i have injected rootScope

Comment: @AlphaDog what is the error now?

Comment: @Sajeetharan it says 'undefined'

Comment: it can't be. is there a way i can check your current code?

Answer (score 0):

I have made sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wn7upsnp/) for your problem,I hope this will resolve your issue.Below is the sample code

```
angular.module('MainApp', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

        $scope.wtsdata = {}; //it can be array too then []
        $scope.selectCustomer = function(item) {
            $scope.item = item;
            if (item.length === 8) {
                $scope.getCustomer(item);
                console.log("Check" + $scope.wtsdata);
            }

        };

        $scope.getCustomer = function(customer_id) {

            $scope.wtsdata = 'Data fetched from service';
            /*ABCServices.wts.customer.customerList({
                customerId: customer_id
            }).then(function(data) {

                console.log("^^^^^ABC show^^^^^");
                $scope.wtsdata = data;

                console.log($scope.wtsdata);

            });*/

        };
    });
```